# Quick sort partition for dummies

Tags: java

Can anyone please explain why the index was swapped in this code and not the content of the array? And also why the index was returned as well?

```
public static int partition(int low, int high) { 
  int pivot = a[low];
  int i = low - 1;
  int j = high + 1; 

  while (i < j) { 
    for (i++; a[i] < pivot; i++); 
    for (j--; a[j] > pivot; j--);
       if (i < j) 
          swap(i, j); 
  } 
  return j;
}
```

Comment: What's `a`, and what's `swap`? This context will most likely help answering

Comment: And why do you think that text written now (on your request) will be more helpful than the tons and tons of material that have been written on quicksort before? Like http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaAlgorithmsQuicksort/article.html ... in other words: did you do *any* prior research?

Comment: Where's your `swap()` method?

Comment: `static void swap(int i, int j) { int tmp = a[i]; a[i] = a[j]; a[j] = i; };`

Comment: What research have you done?

Comment: @GhostCat OP doesn't lack prior research, quite the opposite: he wonders why the specific code he saw breaks his expectation. General text on QuickSort is not what he's looking for.

Comment: Now we haven’t seen the `swap()` method (not even its Javadoc), but I bet it does swap the array content; certainly not the indices (`i` and `j` are local to `partition()` and cannot be altered by `swap()`).